# Iterate over unique dates on a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
id        date      time    dif
01  2020-04-02  09:44:00
02  2020-04-02  09:50:23
03  2020-04-02  09:54:56
04  2020-04-03  10:24:42
05  2020-04-03  10:32:12
06  2020-04-03  11:12:21
...
```

What I'm tryng to do is calculate time difference, in minutes, between each row and its previous one per day. So the result should be like this

```
id        date      time    dif
01  2020-04-02  09:44:00      6
02  2020-04-02  09:50:23      4
03  2020-04-02  09:54:56
04  2020-04-03  10:24:42      7
05  2020-04-03  10:32:12     40
06  2020-04-03  11:12:21
...
```

My first thought was to create a list with the unique values of the column date and tried this:

```
import pandas a dp
import numpy as np

...

dates = df.date.unique()

for d in dates:
  df['dif'] = round(df['time'].diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60),0) * -1
```

But I think it isn't so easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])

df['dif'] = df.groupby('date')['time'].diff(-1).dt.total_seconds().div(60).round().mul(-1)
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with subtracting:

```
df['dif'] = (df.groupby('date')['time'].shift(-1)
               .sub(df['time'])
               .dt.total_seconds()
               .div(60)
               .round())
print (df)
   id        date     time   dif
0   1  2020-04-02 09:44:00   6.0
1   2  2020-04-02 09:50:23   5.0
2   3  2020-04-02 09:54:56   NaN
3   4  2020-04-03 10:24:42   8.0
4   5  2020-04-03 10:32:12  40.0
5   6  2020-04-03 11:12:21   NaN
```